# how do I use linux FS with plone

Tags: plone

I don't wish to use Zope server. Would like to use the Linux file system instead of the user created folders in  the site for the users created in any plone site. I am totally new to plone. Is there any good tutorial for the same?Need a very detailed guide.I have installed a standalone version of Plone.

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing Products.Reflecto:

- http://pythonpackages.com/package/products.reflecto

although I'm not sure if Plone 4 support has been added yet.

Comment: It's the only product I know that can do what appears to be wanted, but it has serious limitations.  At least he wants to do it on a Linux system - it was terrible on Windows. afaict you still need to get the code from svn if you want Plone 4 compatibility.  There was a discussion in late 2010 about the changes, but pypi still has nothing more recent than the 2.4 version that was current then.

Comment: Yeah someone should cut a new release

Answer (score 0):

Plone can't run without Zope. When you install Plone it install Zope too. No need to do anything here.

What you want is having the same linux users on your Plone ?

For doing that, you could have an LDAP, your users on linux will be taken from your LDAP, and you just have to plug your Plone to the LDAP.

You can check this presentation : http://www.slideshare.net/claytron/ldap-auth

And take a look at : http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.ldap

Comment: Jihaisse, All I wanted to do is store the files in the linux file folders instead of using the Zope,  Data.fs

Comment: ok, there is this : http://plone.org/products/filesystemstorage but for using it over 1 year, it's not really effecient, it's slow down your site...